Setting up API Gateway Proxy to third party API in AWS
I Have a APIGW which acts as a proxy to a service deployed using ECS. There is a ELB setup to route the requests to the backend service.
I need to add a new endpoint to this APIGW proxy, which would proxy the request to a third party API instead of Integrating it to the ELB.
I have added the HTTP integration to passthrough request to the third party API. However when I hit the API endpoint example.com, it is returning 404. The new endpoint doesn't exist on backend service, it only exists on APIGW and acts as a proxy.
This is an existing infra and I am not sure where things have been setup. There is a cloud front set up with the ELB as origin. I tried adding the third party API as another origin to the cloudfront( not sure if this is the way to make it work), but that is not working as well.
